# How to make a button that switches between two colours?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

This JavaScript will only change the colour one way. How could I make it so only the one button can be dark/selected at a time depending which button you select?

this is for a small log-in window on my site, and I'm trying to make it switch between two tabs/menus. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
var login = document.querySelector('#login');
var signup = document.querySelector('#signup');

login.onclick = function() {

  if (login.style.backgroundColor === "#a8661f") {
    login.style.backgroundColor = "#d18029";
  } else {
    login.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f"
  }

  signup.onclick = function() {
    signup.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f";
  }
  
}
```

```css
#log_in_box {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#log_in_box button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 85px;
  color: white;
  border: 5px solid #a8661f;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

#login {
  background-color: #d18029;
}

#signup {
  background-color: #d18029;
}
```

```html
<div id="log_in_box">
  <div class="box">
    <button id="login" onclick="login()">Log In</button>
    <button id="signup" onclick="signup()">Sign Up</button>
    <h1>Username:</h1>
    <div class="type_box">
      <p>enter your username</p>
    </div>
    <h1>Password:</h1>
    <div class="type_box">
      <p>enter your password</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Java question tag removed -- nothing Java to see here

Comment: You should use the [**`<input>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) tag to allow users to enter their information :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I plan to, just working on the framework!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier for you to use `onfocus` and `onblur`. Try out the below code and see if that's the desired result:

```
var login = document.querySelector('#login');
var signup = document.querySelector('#signup');



login.onfocus = function() {
  login.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f";
}
login.onblur = function() {
  login.style.backgroundColor = "#d18029";
}

signup.onfocus = function() {
  signup.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f";
}
signup.onblur = function() {
  signup.style.backgroundColor = "#d18029";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can flip back and forth between the colors by switching the button color depending on which button is currently active

```
var login = document.querySelector('#login');
var signup = document.querySelector('#signup');


login.onclick = function(){
    login.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f";
    signup.style.backgroundColor = "#d18029";
}

signup.onclick = function(){
    signup.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f";
    login.style.backgroundColor = "#d18029";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more optimised solution

```
var login = document.querySelector('#login');
var signup = document.querySelector('#signup');

function changeColor(elem1, elem2) {
  elem1.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f";
  elem2.style.backgroundColor = "#d18029";
}
login.onclick = function() {
  changeColor(login, signup);
}
signup.onclick = function() {
  changeColor(signup, login);
}
```

I hope it helps.